# What is the best forecasting model for time series data?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a time series data (1 minute and sometimes 5 minute data) data I would like use `forecasting` package to forecast couple hours ahead.

Here is my data:

```
dput(head(p,20))
structure(list(time = structure(c(1373889420, 1373889480, 1373889540, 
1373889600, 1373889660, 1373889720, 1373889780, 1373889840, 1373889900, 
1373889960, 1373890020, 1373890080, 1373890140, 1373890200, 1373890260, 
1373890320, 1373890380, 1373890440, 1373890500, 1373890560), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), cpu = c(2.25892, 2.04144, 
5.04823333333333, 4.9947, 1.72982857142857, 4.82655, 3.6168625, 
4.7357, 2.42683333333333, 3.62635, 5.02315714285714, 2.57147142857143, 
7.16005, 2.34253333333333, 2.82315714285714, 5.17668, 2.2899375, 
6.92, 5.172375, 4.63735), name = c("servers", "servers", "servers", 
"servers", "servers", "servers", "servers", "servers", "servers", 
"servers", "servers", "servers", "servers", "servers", "servers", 
"servers", "servers", "servers", "servers", "servers")), .Names = c("time", 
"cpu", "name"), row.names = c(1116L, 1411L, 123L, 226L, 1014L, 
435L, 538L, 569L, 1081L, 342L, 74L, 865L, 178L, 890L, 281L, 166L, 
1035L, 143L, 112L, 91L), class = "data.frame")

x.xts <- xts(p$cpu, p$time)
x.ts <- as.ts(x.xts)
x.ets <- ets(x.ts)
x.fore <- forecast(x.ets, h=120)
f<-data.frame(x.fore$mean)
    DateTime<-tail(z,1)$time
f$DATE <- DateTime + 60 * (seq_len(nrow(f))-1)
    colnames(f)<-c("cpu", "time")
    f$name<-c("forecast")
```

I see that `cpu` is the same for all future data times:

```
 cpu                time     name
1 6.020207 2013-07-15 11:57:00 forecast
2 6.020207 2013-07-15 11:58:00 forecast
3 6.020207 2013-07-15 11:59:00 forecast
4 6.020207 2013-07-15 12:00:00 forecast
5 6.020207 2013-07-15 12:01:00 forecast
6 6.020207 2013-07-15 12:02:00 forecast
```

Is there a better forecasting model besides `ets` for time series data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this looks good.  There is no pattern within the data to be extracted. It is all "noise" so a flat forecast is fine.

Now, if you want to correct for the two outliers at period 13 and 18 then no it wouldn't be good.  Are these outliers??  Also, do you have any causal variables that explain the Y?

Comment: what model would you chose to forecast data points like this, etc, holtwinters, arima?

Comment: How can I answer your questions when you don't answer mine?  Are those two data points outliers???  To answer yours, I don't agree with using a specific model and forcing it to the data. would you borrow a friends glasses and try and see with them?  No.  I believe in using heuristics to use the ACF/PACF to identify patterns from the noise.  ETS doesn't do this for you.

Comment: yes, those data points are outliers. I need to script this, within script I could pick ets, arima, holtwinters. My question is which one of these models is best suited for time series data.

Comment: There is no one model to use.  You have a make or buy decision.  We have software that detects the outliers at period 13 and 18 and doesn't assume a model form.                             
       
Go to www.autobox.com for more          
                                                                                                                             
Y(T) =  3.6301                                                                                                     
       + 3.2899             :PULSE          2007
       + 3.5299             :PULSE          2002

Comment: FYI:The forecast would be 3.63 vs 6.02 from ets.

Comment: @user1471980: There is no "best model for time series data". You need to apply domain knowledge to come up with an actual model: how is the data generated, what kind of relationships might there be between time 1 and time 2? What other data might you have (number of users, number of processes, time zone of users, types of processes, etc, etc) that might feed into a model to give you better answers? If you can do that, the technique will be more obvious. As Tom Reilly says, the short bit of data you supplied looks pretty random so it's not clear you can do any better than going with an average.